# Find the developable surface from turning back edge

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

> Find the equation of the developable surface which has the curve $ r(t)=(6t, 3t^2, 2t^3)$ as turning back edge.

I know that if I am starting from a family $F(x, y, z, A) = 0$, I solve the system $F=0,$ $F'=0$ and $F''=0$ by removing the parameter A between the equations and I find the turning back edge. But to start from a curve which is a turning back edge, I have no idea and I did not find any solved problems.

Comment: You already posted exactly the same question yesterday [on this site](https://www.reddit.com/r/MathHelp/comments/s5bsm7/developable_surface_from_curve/) and had the same questions: what is your work on the subject ?

Comment: I had never seen the term "turning back edge" : do you mean the "striction line" ?

Comment: The course isn't in english so I translated directly, but I explained that "turning back edge" can be found by
solving that system when a family is given. I do not know the exact term in english. But I think it is indeed called striction line. And about the other site, I do not know how to start, calculating first and second fundamental form won't help, curvature won't help...

Comment: You can find different properties of the striction curve [here](https://mathcurve.com/courbes3d.gb/striction/striction.shtml)

Comment: You want the tangent developable surface of the curve $C$. This is the ruled surface where the ruling through $p\in C$ is the tangent line of $C$ at $p$.